# Why does SpaceIL's Beresheet landing graphics show m\s instead of m/s?

Tags: mathematics, software, language, spaceil

I just noticed that the software displayed in the [video of the landing](https://youtu.be/N8WbGibkZcE?t=104) had the velocity and acceleration units with a backslash (m\s) instead of the usual convention of a forward slash (m/s).

Out of curiosity, is there any technical reason for this or just an oversight from the software engineers?

---

Display of data from the SpaceIL Beresheet spacecraft during its Moon landing attempt is in English but in the display of speeds, the heading is `Velocity [m\s]` where one would expect the units to be written `[m/s]` with a "forward slash" but instead uses a "backslash".

[image: Beresheet Moon Landing scientific display video screenshot] from [this video](https://youtu.be/MHqjVMTdjM8?t=515)

Comment: What is "the stream"?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the link to the [video](https://youtu.be/N8WbGibkZcE?t=104)

Comment: Might be a symptom of whatever microsoft has been suffering from all these years.

Comment: [How are inline fractions written in modern Hebrew? Which way does the slash tilt?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/34672/27544) Since Hebrew is written right to left, I wonder if the slashes used in inline fractions in scientific writing are backslashes and this is a residually incomplete translation.

Comment: As a student of physics in Israel, I noticed these in graph sometimes. No hidden meaning there. Just laziness.