# What IMU did Beresheet fly?

Tags: beresheet, imu

Is there public information on the inertial measurement unit used by Beresheet during its landing attempt? More generally, is there information on the hardware flown on that vehicle?

Comment: There's a fair degree of information on Space IL's [website](https://www.spaceil.com/home-page), but you may need the assistance of a Hebrew-reading person to help you navigate to any technical information on the website.

Comment: It should be easy to track down, very few IMUs will have [backwards slashes](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40584) (humor)